# Form submit to new page with javascript json array data

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms

Use of fetch is very common but it not going to load new page with data, it just send data and receive data.

How to use it like normal HTML form submit but instead of using name I can send data like fetch and but open new link as form action does. Open New Page.

If i use form action I have to use name attribute but there is some much data so name can be too much for it also it can be array also that is hard pass for using name for.

Is it possible to send data like form html but without name that open a new page with all data which get send via.

Only I want to send an array which post to new page as a json data.

```html
<!-- Here is example of using alpine and using fetch to send data it return whole page but i can't do anything with it -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<div x-data="{order:''}">
  <form @submit.prevent="fetch('/user/payment', {method: 'POST', headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},body: JSON.stringify(order)})">
    <div class="mt-6">
      <button><span>Proceed to RazorPay<br>₹ 747</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<Br>
<Br>
<!-- I like something Like this so action page but here i like to send array of data -->
  <form method="POST" action= '/user/payment'>
  <input type="text" name="order"/>
    <div class="mt-6">
      <button><span>Proceed to RazorPay<br>₹ 747</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Fetch follows `30X` redirects and returns the data from the last redirect. Are you trying to redirect the page as well?'

Comment: just like new page like form action="" but using javascript to send data instead for using html form

Comment: using name is little bit long as i have that data in json i like to send that to just like form action="" style which open totally new page.

Comment: Well, if you want your fetch to act like a real form, why don't you just use a real form? By the way, for a real form you can submit it in a new tab with the attribute `target="_blank"` in your `<form>` element.

Answer (score -1):

After using fetch, you can change the url of the window like this `window.location.replace = your_url`.

Comment: but i like to open new page with all data send to new page.

Comment: Do you mean you need to (1) send data using fetch, and get a response, and then (2) send the same data to a URL and force the page to reload?

Comment: You can have a form with an action attribute, and add a button (not a submit button) with a click event. When the button is clicked -> send the form data via javascript (using something like `ajaxSubmit` functions from Ajax Form Plugin or the jQuery serialize function), and then do a regular form submit programmatically using javascript (ex: `document.getElementById('#formId').submit();`)